# How to use word-wrap feature in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, line, word-wrap

I am using `Eclipse for PHP Developers` edition and I am trying find how to enable word-wrap feature in eclipse as I have large code with long lines.

Is there any plugin available or Eclipse has it own word-wrap feature?

My Eclipse details:

[image]

I have no idea how to do this so I will thankful If you guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Word wrap can be enabled with a simple click in vanilla Eclipse Neon and later. https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M4/#word-wrap

Answer (score 1):

It's not a feature.

See http://bugs.eclipse.org/35779 and http://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap .

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this eclipse plug-in on my eclipse.
http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/word-wrap/

After installing this plug-in, right click on editor, ”Toggle Word Wrap” will show up on menu!